# compose _mm256_cmp_ps and _mm256_blend_ps

Tags: simd, avx, avx2

I'm trying to do a projected maximum of pairs in avx2

```cpp
inline void invoke_cmp_blend(__m256& a0, __m256& a1, __m256& b0, __m256& b1, __m256& out0, __m256& out1)
{
    auto proj = &_mm256_div_ps;
    auto proj_a = proj(a0, a1);
    auto proj_b = proj(b0, b1);
    
    auto mask_ab = _mm256_cmp_ps(proj_a, proj_b, _CMP_LT_OS);

    out0 = _mm256_blend_ps(a0, b0, mask_ab); // error C2664: '__m256 _mm256_blend_ps(__m256,__m256,const int)': cannot convert argument 3 from '__m256' to 'const int'
    out1 = _mm256_blend_ps(a1, b1, mask_ab); // error C2664: '__m256 _mm256_blend_ps(__m256,__m256,const int)': cannot convert argument 3 from '__m256' to 'const int'
}
```

However, the output of `_mm256_cmp_ps` is a batch of `float`s and `_mm256_blend_ps` wants an int;

Comment: You need a variable-blend, a different instruction with a different intrinsic.  `_mm256_blendv_ps` takes a control vector.

Comment: > replace `_mm256_blend_ps` -> `_mm256_blendv_ps`. Thanks!